# How to use Javascript without creating variables?

Tags: javascript, scripting

I have the following lines of code which offsets cursor position of an HTML element by 6, so that it is at the end of the text 'hi how' to the last char entered.

HTML

```
<div id="editable">
   hi how
</div>
```

JS

```
var range = document.createRange();
var sel = window.getSelection();
range.setStart(document.getElementById("editable").childNodes[0], 6);
range.collapse(true);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
document.getElementById("editable").focus();
```

I am running the above JS code in a testing framework, but there seems to be a bug in it, which doesn't allow me to save variables. My question is there a way to perform the same functionality as above, without creating variables 'range', and 'sel'.
I tried doing it but failed at where line where we have to offset its starting point. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One bug is this typo: `document.getElementById("editable");.childNodes[0], 6` which will result in a SyntaxError. If your Javascript framework doesn't permit variables, I think the framework can be considered to be broken, and the best thing to do would be to find another

Comment: Hi there. It is a testing framework, not a JS framework that I am running tests on. I am looking to know if there is a solution for the problem I have stated. I can't change framework at this time.

Comment: You probably got downvoted because you are already focusing on a (uncommon) solution, instead of providing information that would help us investigate the core issue. For example: Which test framework are you using? How do you arrive at the conclusion that you can’t declare variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.variableName performs the same function. 
Taking the example above:

```
window.range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(document.getElementById("editable").childNodes[0], 6);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
range.setStart(document.getElementById("editable");.childNodes[0], 6);
```

this need to be like below

```
range.setStart(document.getElementById("editable").childNodes[0], 6);
```

no semicolon inside an expression

Comment: Thanks for stating that.  I have edited my question.